# I don't know why UCC27324 getting hot in normal condition

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, pwm, mosfet-driver, powermosfet

I have some question about UCC27324P MOSFET driver.

I have experiment using UCC27324D (8-DIP type) and UCC27324P (SMD type) via this circuit.

DIP type driver works fine with no problem same condition.

But SMD type driver when 3.3 V PWM signal engaged, temperature increase so fast.

I don't know what I miss. Here is circuit and datasheet.

[image: Circuit]

[UCC27324 data sheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ucc27324.pdf?ts=1638154271251&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)

Comment: How are you heatsinking it? Did you notice the thermal resistance to air (table 7.4) is twice as high for the SOIC package? What's your calculated power dissipation? What temperature rise does this give both packages? Does that match your measurements?

Comment: @user1818839 UCC27324 doesn't have heatsink design. I didn't noticed difference of thermal resistanse because it isn't power IC.. DIP type IC didn'r rising Only SMD type heated up fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probable cause are the missing gate resistors. It remains still questionable if the pull-down gate resistors are really needed as they also load the driver.

Comment: Sir, u mean serial connection of gate output to MOSFET gate?? If is right what is common value of that resister??

Comment: @박성재 Yes, he meant these resistors (a.k.a. gate stopper resistors) as shown in the datasheet. Typical value depends on the switching frequency: The Ciss of the MOSFETs and the gate stopper resistors form a low-pass RC filter. So the cut-off frequency of this filter should be way beyond the maximum frequency. In some cases the minimum duty cycle (i.e. the minimum pulse duration) should be taken into account, but not here. So, the value should be high enough not to chop off the PWM signal, and low enough not to exceed the max output current of the driver IC.

Comment: @박성재 Why you encircled the 3.3V on other IC? You do supply the UCCxx with 12V. What is the PWM frequency? Did you calculate the power loss using formulas, with known MOSFET capacitance & PWM frequency & supply voltage ?

Comment: @ Marko Buršič because I use stm32f1 it use 3.3V level. I tested PWM frequency is 17kHz and 1.7kHz but its not effected result.I didn't caculate power loss..

Comment: @MarkoBuršič thank  you sir! That problem which you told me was right exactly!

Comment: @MarkoBuršič 
So I connect 10K ohm resistor to driver output between MOSFET gate, and removed 10K ohm resistor which attached on MOSFET gate between GND. Now finally problem had solved! I can't measure fan out current of driver in accuracy but it might 0.2A I think.

Comment: @박성재 10k is too big resistance, you can put a small resistor like 10 ohm, 22,...